Как сделать так, чтобы клиент перестал присылать тело HTTP после редиректа(303 See Other) от сервера
У меня есть веб-сервер на Си, который работает на Linux(Debian). Есть варианты страниц, которые он может отправить:

http://localhost:port/login
http://localhost:port/registration
http://localhost:port/rooms
http://localhost:port/rooms/{name_room}

Проблема получается когда пользователь регистрируется(отправляет POST на сервер с '/registration').

Сервер после регистрации пользователя присылает ответ c кодом 303:
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n
Location: /rooms\n\n

После чего клиент делает запрос с GET, но странный(в его теле присутствует введенные им данные на странице '/registration').
GET /rooms HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.3.35:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/png,image/svg+xml,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.3.35:8000/registration
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://192.168.3.35:8000/registration
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Priority: u=0, i

login=dima&password=dima&username=asdf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой мне нужно отправить ответ от сервера чтобы клиент очистил HTTP тело при следующих запросах?

У GET-запросов не может быть тела, а повторяющийся заголовок Referer создаёт очень сильные подозрения, что это, например, ваш сервер забывает чистить у себя информацию после предыдущего запроса и клиент ни в чём не виноват

В общем, я бы на всякий случай проверил tcpdump-ом или wireshark-ом (или чем-то аналогичным) что там реально ходит по сети.

@ansreymal , спасибо, вы были правы
